# If $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal in $R[X]$, is $M \cap R$ a maximal ideal of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Theorem B on the first page of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-041-01/S0002-9939-1973-0318123-8/S0002-9939-1973-0318123-8.pdf) states the following : If $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal in $R[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$, then $M \cap R$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

With this, as every prime ideal of a ring is not maximal, I am wondering if there is a counterexample to the following : If $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R[X]$, then $M \cap R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. This claim has been speculated to be true by the instructor in my algebraic geometry course.

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $R=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and $M=(pX-1)$.  Then $R[X]/M\cong R[1/p]=\mathbb{Q}$ is a field so $M$ is maximal, but $M\cap R=0$ is not maximal in $R$.

A commutative ring $R$ with the property that every maximal ideal in $R[X]$ has maximal intersection with $R$ is called a *Jacobson ring*.  This property has many equivalent formulations; for instance, it is equivalent to saying that every prime ideal in $R$ is an intersection of maximal ideals.  A general version of the Nullstellensatz says that any finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is Jacobson.  It follows that if $R$ is Jacobson, then any maximal ideal in any finitely generated $R$-algebra pulls back to a maximal ideal in $R$.  (In the case that $R=k[X]$ for an algebraically closed field $k$, this implies the classical Nullstellensatz over $k$.)

Comment: Theorem 27 in Kaplansky's book *Commutative Rings* implies that every maximal ideal in $R[x]$ contracts to a maximal ideal in $R$ if and only if $R$ is a Hilbert ring (=Jacobson ring): see the definition on p. 18 or, explicitly, Exercise 9 on p. 20.  Any commutative algebra that is finitely generated over a field is Jacobson and so has the desired property.

  @Eric Wofsey's $R$ is a local domain that is not a field, so it is not a Jacobson ring.